# Ambiguous type inference

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I'm getting a compiler error from Swift 3.0.1 that's got me stumped. The error states that there's ambiguity in the type of a computed property but I can't see how.

I have a protocol `Generic` with a property `root`. This protocol has a generic constraint that `root` must be a subclass of type `Root`.

```
class Root { }

protocol Generic {
    associatedtype RootType: Root
    var root: RootType { get }
}
```

I then define a protocol extension that states:

> If a `Generic` is a subclass of `Root`, return `self` from the `root` property.

So basically: if it's already a `Root`, you can just forward `self`.

```
extension Generic where Self: Root {
    var root: Self {
        return self
    }
}
```

I also have a `GenericWrapper` class that is a subclass of `Root` and wraps an instance of `Generic` (to perform `Root` operations with a `Generic` proxy).

```
class GenericWrapper<T: Generic>: Root {
    var generic: T

    init(generic: T) {
        self.generic = generic
    }
}
```

Finally, I define a `Specialised` protocol, and an extension to it that states:

> If a `Specialised` implements `Generic`, return a `GenericWrapper` from the `root` property.

```
protocol Specialised { }
extension Specialised where Self: Generic {
    var root: GenericWrapper<Self> {
        get {
            return GenericWrapper(generic: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I try to implement a class that implements `Generic` and `Specialised`, I'm getting this error.

```
class SpecialisedImplementation: Generic, Specialised {
    // errors:
    //   Ambiguous inference of associated type 'RootType': 'GenericWrapper<SpecialisedImplementation>' vs. 'SpecialisedImplementation'
    //   Matching requirement 'root' to this declaration inferred associated type to 'GenericWrapper<SpecialisedImplementation>'
    //   Matching requirement 'root' to this declaration inferred associated type to 'SpecialisedImplementation'
}
```

The reason I'm confused is because the ambiguity states that the `SpecialisedImplementation` class matches the requirement from the extension to `Generic` when `Generic: Root`, but `SpecialisedImplementation` doesn't inherit from `Root` so it shouldn't surely?

Comment: I've opened a bug for this: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with this being a compiler bug and have opened a [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3145). For anyone else experiencing a similar issue, I've managed to work around it by removing the `Self` requirement from the `Generic` extension:

```
class Root { }

protocol Generic {
    associatedtype RootType: Root
    var root: RootType { get }
}

extension Generic where Self: Root {
    // ===================
    // don't use Self here
    // ===================
    var root: Root {
        return self
    }
}

class GenericWrapper<T: Generic>: Root {
    var generic: T

    init(generic: T) {
        self.generic = generic
    }
}

protocol Specialised { }
extension Specialised where Self: Generic {
    var root: GenericWrapper<Self> {
        get {
            return GenericWrapper(generic: self)
        }
    }
}

class SpecialisedImplementation: Generic, Specialised {
    // no errors!
}
```

Comment: I've heard back from the compiler team that the bug I was experiencing has already been fixed on the Swift master branch, so should be fixed in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

The diagnostic is confusing; the real problem here is that it's too circular and it's going beyond what the compiler can handle.

It tries to resolve `Generic`, and finds it can't without assuming that `SpecialisedImplementation` is a subclass of `Root` (which isn't true, but it's desperate to find a way to make it work). And it tries to make `Specialised` work, but it can only do that if `Generic` already worked, but the only way to get `Generic` to work is to make it `Root`.

You want it to assume everything you say is true at the same time, but it's not that smart. It's trying to build it up piecemeal, one protocol at a time, and gets confused. Open a bugreport at bugs.swift.org.

(But this is also almost certainly *wildly* too complicated. In particular, I'd work hard to get rid of that `Root` class if you possibly can; mixing protocols and classes and generics all together is a recipe for lots of very confusing compiler problems.)

Comment: Thanks Rob. I agree that this is hideously complex (unfortunately `Root` maps to a Foundation class in my abstraction so I can't get rid of it). My assumption was that the compiler should ignore the first extension though, because it's perfectly valid for me to only implement `Generic` and provide an implementation for `var root` in that class/struct. But once I provide the`SpecialisedImplementation` extension, which is providing an inferred `RootType`, it gets confused and gives me an error. Despite the complexity, I think what I'm trying to do is technically _valid_, so I might open a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm addressing the error in general.

> matching requirement 'afuncName(:)' to this declaration inferred
>   associated type to 'SomeType'

This means:

- The protocol has an associatedType.
- The associatedType is used across multiple functions but **different** types are being passed. Hence the protocol requirements are not satisfied.

Imagine I wrote this protocol.

```
protocol Athlete{
    associatedtype ShoeSize

    func run(with: ShoeSize)
    func jump(with: ShoeSize)
}
```

And now I try to conform to it like this:

```
class Person: Athlete{
    func run(with: Int){ // Line A
        print("running")
    }

    func jump(with: String){ // Line B
        print("jumping")
    }
}
```

At Line **A**, the ShoeSize associatedtype is being inferred as an `Int`. So for the other `jump` function it expects that its input type to be an `Int` as well. But it's getting a `String` hence it throws and error.

Same with Line **B**. Only that this time the ShoeSize associatedtype is being inferred as a `String`. So for the other `run` function it expects that its input type to be an `String` as well. But it's getting a `Int` hence it throws and error.

Basically by doing such I got the 2 errors below:

```
note: matching requirement 'jump(with:)' to this declaration inferred associated type to 'String'
 func jum(with: String){


 note: matching requirement 'run(with:)' to this declaration inferred associated type to 'Int'
 func run(with: Int){
```

What's the solution?

both run & jump should have identical inputs because both of them are restricted by the associatedtype